# Podcast search API

Tags: api, web-services, itunes, podcast

Is there any podcast directory search API out there apart from the iTunes search API? I have looked around but could not find anything useful. Can I use feedburner for this? Is there a search API for feedburner too?

Comment: @JustSid i have provided links to some apis and mashups

Answer (score 88):

**APIs**

[Digital Podcast Search Service](http://www.digitalpodcast.com/podcastsearchservice/)

[CCHits API](http://code.cchits.net/index.php?title=API)

[Mixcloud API](http://www.mixcloud.com/developers/documentation/)

**iTunes**

[iTunes Store Web Service Search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) or parse the rss feeds or itune tags in rss feeds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171230/php-access-to-itunes-tags-in-an-rss-feed)

**Mashups**

[Last.fm Podcast Finder](http://jamidwyer.com/lastpod/index.php)

[Podbop](http://podbop.org/)

[Podfeed](http://podfeed.net/)

and more mashup directory [here](http://www.programmableweb.com/mashups/directory/1?q=podcast)

Comment: Information for ITunes search has moved: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for the same thing, and found [Digital Podcast Search Service](http://www.digitalpodcast.com/podcastsearchservice/). I haven't tried using it yet.